# ServerName and ServerAlias and do we need to flushdns after apply in vhost?

Tags: domain-name-system, apache-2.4, virtualhost, 301-redirect

I have applied ServerName and ServerAlias in my vhost and from [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#serveralias) it is mentioned that Servername is hostname and port that server used to identify itself while ServerAlias is the alternate names for a host. Now my website is works in https+www.example.com, so I've set my

`ServerName as "www.example.com"` and my `ServerAlias put it as "example.com"(Previously was comment out, now I tried to apply it back)`

so that when I type "example.com" in the browser, it will redirect me to "https://www.example.com" (please correct me if I understand it wrongly). But even after I apply those, it still doesn't redirect me, do I need to flushdns and stop-start my DNS? Because there are a few times that all changes have been done, restart apache and nothing reflects until I flushdns, is this a must? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I cannot leave comments because I'm new but you should look at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#usecanonicalname

I am assuming you are using Apache and [name based virtualhosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html)

Again, sorry I couldn't leave this as a comment.

Comment: Adding a comment to test if you can comment down below, can you try add a comment below?

Comment: Yeah, if you reply I can comment.

Comment: I did try to add UseCanonicalName but with On instead because I have an issue where my logs showing rewritecond input= 'www.example.com' but when I type 'example.com' in the browser(which I expect it to redirect from example.com to https+www.example.com) but it doesn't because of host of request header showing 'example.com' instead. What should I do now?

Comment: @Petri, hmm, not sure. Let me get this straight, you want the server to use the URL as passed by the browser example.com and www.example.com but you don't want one redirecting to the other.

Comment: @Petri You might be able to use .htaccess to rewrite requests for example.com to http:// example.com. Not sure what your logs record a rewrite. You have a <virtualhost> for example.com or is it the default server?

Comment: Actually my website currently works without any issue with http+www.example.com and is live now. But then I received a request to perform redirection where when a user type example.com it will automatically redirect them to https+www.example.com. I just need it to redirect from example.com(when typing this in browser) to https+www.example.com. I doesn't need it to redirect to other. And yes, I'm now using .htaccess to perform the redirection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107015/discussion-between-petri-and-admiral-noisy-bottom).

Comment: @Petri in case you missed this link in the chat, it might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www

Answer (score 1):

The [`ServerName`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#servername) and all hostnames in the [`ServerAlias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#serveralias) are treated the same i.e. the same configuration applies to all the hostnames specified in both directives on the `<VirtualHost>` section. The only difference is that the `ServerName` is used as identification, and cannot therefore contain more than a single hostname. That's why there's a separate `ServerAlias` directive for the additional hostnames. That's not an obvious solution, but that's how Apache has decided to arrange this. E.g. Nginx handles this differently, having a single [`server_name`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name) directive that can have multiple hostnames.

**There's no automatic redirection from `ServerAlias` to `ServerName`**, but you'd need to configure it e.g. by using a separate `<VirtualHost>` section. This example redirects all `example.com` & `*.example.com` to canonical `www.example.com`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    Redirect / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    . . .
</VirtualHost>
```

Notice that the `ServerName example.com` doesn't imply that `example.com` is the canonical name, as there a redirection from the domain apex to the `www` subdomain.

Comment: Let's say I have VirtualHost A with ServerName example.com now(only have one now), if I want to redirect *.example.com I need to add another new VirtualHost B below with the rest I suppose is the same configuration right?

Comment: That's one way to do it, and I think it's the most simple and straightforward solution.

Comment: I'm sorry but another stupid question from me, if my current live website is https+www and I need to redirect from example.com(actually example.com is not existed, just a request that when user type example.com in the browser, it will go to current live site) to my current live site, I still need to add VirtualHost B too or I can just put ServerName www.example.com and ServerAlias as example.com will be good enough? (I just need it to redirect from example.com to https+www.example.com)